# Removing Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

I've installed Exchange 2010 on one server with 10 mailboxes, 1 distribution group and done mostly basic configuration limits of Exchange. Later on it was decided to move it to Virtual Machine so I've installed 2nd Exchange 2010 server on that virtual server and both servers are now visible. 
First server has pop3 connector running that gets emails from external servers. There's no mx running yet as the server was on dynamic IP when setting up started. Now it has static IP so port forwarding will be done to point to the new exchange server.

I've started Local Move Request for all mailboxes, and it finished successfully.

What else should I do?
How I make sure nothing gets lost?
How do I remove 1st server permanently making sure nothing gets broken?

Comment: Any reason to not have done a P2V migration, rather than a full re-install?

Comment: Yes. The machine (2 CPUs with 6-8 cores each, with 32gb of ram) that hosts it has SharePoint, Exchange, Office, Pop3 connector, 10 other user apps etc. Basically this is really not a good setup including problems with DNS and some things won't install because of Office install on server (for example GFI products). I've taken it over in that shape and proposed to create AD, DNS to Virtual1, create AD, DNS to Virtual2, Next virtual server will take SharePoint and all users applications, last one is Exchange only. Server is Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Comment: It's one big server for 10 users which i prefer to have all things separated and running smoothly. But now I need to remove all stuff from HOST and when it's done and virtual machines are running i will wipe HOST clean and reinstall it, and start up Virtual again.

Comment: This sounds like a whole lot of trouble (and money) for 10 users.

Comment: Why are Office and the other user apps on the server?

Comment: Well it's not my choice. Client wants, client gets. The use Remote Desktop on that server to work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the mailboxes have been moved, and the new server is doing the pop3 connector work, you should be able to just run the uninstall on the physical server and the uninstall should clean up everything else.

Comment: Will test it soon :-)